# Does git have an option to show the commits to be merged before performing the merge?

Tags: git

For example, when I merge from master -> production, I'd like to see a list of the commits before I, err, commit to them. Something like:

```
$ git merge --doublecheck master
Commits to merge:
1292642 fix foo
3c0f30b cleanup bar
Do you want to proceed? (y/n)
```

Comment: [git help rev-list](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use revision range double-dot `..` syntax to do this:

```
git log --oneline --graph <branch-to-merge-into>..<branch-to-be-merged>
```

The output will be all commits in `<branch-to-be-merged>` that aren't in `<branch-to-merge-into>`.

You can learn more about this and other revision range syntaxes in the [Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) section of the [**FREE online Pro Git book**](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: And you can omit the left-hand-side if it’s your current branch. `git log ..master` in this case.

Comment: and you could create a git alias to make the behaviour you want scripted

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent Git from committing automatically with the `--no-commit` and `--no-ff` flags:

```
git merge master --no-commit --no-ff
```

If the current branch and master have diverged, then `--no-commit` is enough. If master is simply a couple of revisions ahead then Git will automatically fast-forward, and there isn't really a commit in this case. The `--no-ff` prevents this automatic fast forward.

If you do this, the changes that result from the merge will be in a pending state, not committed. I do this when doing code-reviews, as it's easy to diffs in this state. If you do this often it's practical to create an alias for it in your `~/.gitconfig`, for example:

```
rev = merge --no-ff --no-commit
```

In the end, I reset and let Git do the committing, as it generates a nice commit log as the summary of all commit logs of the merged revisions.

Comment: While this shows the result of the merge, it doesn't show which commits are being merged in, which is what the original poster asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Another techniques is to use the `--no-commit` and -`no-ff` option (similar to the `git commit --dry-run` option), so you can see the actual results. See the Examples section of the merge(1) man page.

see also [SO/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option) and [git merge without auto commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8641053/717355)

Comment: While this shows the result of the merge, it doesn't show which commits are being merged in, which is what the original poster asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken some of the suggestions here and written a little script, [`git-safemerge`](https://gist.github.com/wolever/6416735):

```
 $ git safemerge master
 Commits:
  * bc911ef Fix bug in widget
  * e80f8d1 Clean things up

 Changes:
  foo.py   |  12 ++--
  bar.py   |  35 +++++-----
  2 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 47 deletions(-)

 Fast-forward: not possible

 Continue merging master into prod? (y/n)
```

It's available at: https://gist.github.com/wolever/6416735