# How to interpret a merge commit in git?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Here's an example of a commit history, where some files were added (`a`, `b`, and `c`):

```
* 51c3dd7 (HEAD -> master) add c
| * ded49bb (my_branch) add b
|/
* f3cea38 add a
```

Suppose I start a merge from `my_branch` into the current branch (`HEAD`) using `git merge --no-commit --no-ff my_branch`, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8640887).

Now, while in the `MERGING` state, I unstage everything, followed by `git commit` to complete the merge.

As a result I still get a merge commit, even though there is actually no change to `HEAD`:

```
*   5990dce (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'my_branch'
|\
| * ded49bb (my_branch) add b
* | 51c3dd7 add c
|/
* f3cea38 a
```

I find this quite confusing. Shouldn't the merge automatically abort?

Of course this is a trivial example, but a similar confusion may arise after a "selective" merge, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292109).

Should a merge commit be interpreted as: "Something may, or may not, have been added from this branch?"

Comment: You merged the history of `my_branch` that `master` doesn't have.

Comment: You shouldn't be merging those at all, imho. Git tracks changes, it doesn't care if you change something back the way it was, the history should remain.

Comment: I personally prefer flat histories (no branching whatsoever), but your case makes no sense to me: why would you unstage everything a branch staged?

Comment: If you want to keep the (soon to be undone) change in history, your way is ok. If not, you should rewrite the branch (for example `git rebase -i`) to not contain it at all and then merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find this quite confusing.

Many people say that very often about Git. :-)

Before I get any further, let me make this terminology note.  The word *merge* here can be both adjective—*a merge commit*—and verb: *merge another commit*.  The adjective form can become a noun, when *a merge commit* is shortened to just *a merge*.  It's important to distinguish between the verb *to merge* and the adjective (or noun) *a merge commit*.  A *merge commit* is simply any commit with two or more parent commits.  We typically use the `git merge` command to start the merge-as-a-verb process, which ends by making one of these merge-as-a-noun things.

(The `git merge` command can be told to do merge-as-a-verb without making a merge-as-a-noun.  There are more commands in Git that can also do merge-as-a-verb without making a merge-as-a-noun.  We don't need to worry about them here, though.)

> Shouldn't the merge automatically abort?

No: Git assumes you meant what you said.

You said: *Start the process of merging, but don't finish it, even if it seems to work.  Let me fuss with the index, then complete the merge myself later, by running `git commit`.*<sup>1</sup>  To make sense of this, you need to understand the roles of the *index*, also known as the staging area and sometimes the cache.

To put it as simply as I think it can be put, the index is *where you build the next commit you will make*.  This is true whether or not the next commit is going to be a merge commit.  For ordinary non-merge commits, the index simply holds copies of every file:  It starts out with a copy of every file from the *current* commit, then you overwrite some of these using `git add` to copy the work-tree version into the index, replacing the old current-commit version.  If you `git add` a totally *new* file, the action taken is the same, it's just that the file is new rather than replaced.  If you `git rm` a file—with or without `--cached`—you are removing the file from the index, so that the file *won't* be in the next commit.

During the merge-as-a-verb process, the index expands its role rather a lot, at least in the case of *merge conflicts*.  Here, the index winds up holding (up to) *three* copies of each file.  These are numbered with "higher stage" numbers.  Stage slot zero is for normal files; slots 1-3 are for merge-conflict-state files.  While there are any entries in these higher stage numbers, the index cannot be used to make a commit.  Git forces you to resolve the conflicts first.

Now `git add` has a new function: it tells Git that it should rip out the three higher-stage versions of the file, as well as write into the index the normal stage-zero entry.  You are not doing any of this here, but it is worth mentioning.

Note that `git rm` simply removes the files, regardless of stage-slot numbers.  Meanwhile, `git reset`, like `git add`, acquires a new function: `git reset` copies a file from the current commit to stage-slot zero as usual, but like `git add`, *also* rip out the higher stage-slot entries if they exist.  If the file does not exist in the current commit, `git reset` removes the file from the index.

(In fact, `git add` and `git reset` *always* do this extra work.  It just does nothing when there are no higher stage numbers lying around.  If file `foo.txt` exists only at stage zero as `:0:foo.txt`, removing `:1:foo.txt`—the stage-slot-1 entry for the same file—has no effect.)

In any case, at the end of this merge process, the index has all the files that will go into the new merge commit, just as it has all the files that will go into a normal non-merge commit.  The final `git commit` step notices the information that `git merge` left for it—specifically, the extra parent to use to make the new commit *be* a merge commit (in `.git/MERGE_HEAD`).  So, `git commit` makes a new commit, using the index contents just like any commit, but setting up at least one extra parent as recorded in this `MERGE_HEAD` file.  **All that matters is that the index be in a commit-able state.  Whatever its contents are, those files become the files in the commit.  Every (Git) command you ran between `git merge --no-commit` and `git commit` had, as its true end purpose, some modification to the files in the index.**

---

<sup>1</sup>In relatively recent versions of Git you can run `git merge --continue` to have `git merge` run `git commit` for you.  If you intend to *stop* the merge, use `git merge --abort`, which is a synonym for the positively ancient `git reset --merge`.  (Everyone should have a Git new enough to use `git merge --abort`; once `git merge --continue` is common enough, I'd recommend using that here too.)