# Prevent unnecessary commits with git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

My eyes were all over this page:
[Git merge without auto commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640887/git-merge-without-auto-commit)

I wanted to believe. 
But I tried and reality diverged.

I have this:

```
git fetch origin;
git merge --no-edit origin;
```

this seems to create new commits, even if there were no changes between the remote and the local branch.

I don't think that using

```
 git merge --no-ff origin;
```

or

```
git merge --no-commit origin;
```

are the answers. How can I merge the remote into the local without making a commit if there are no changes? Perhaps not do the merge at all, and first check to see if there is a difference?

**What I am confused about**: I assume `--no-commit` will break if the remote branch has changes that need to be merged into the local branch, because shouldn't that always require a new commit?

Comment: `--no-commit` leaves you in the middle of the merge. If you want to try updating without creating a merge commit *and fail otherwise*, the option is `--ff-only`. If `git merge --no-edit origin` doesn’t display “Already up to date”, then there *were* changes between the remote and the local branch (in the form of commits, not necessarily an actual content difference).

Comment: Is the goal here something like `git pull --rebase`?  I'm not impugning the question, just have limited knowledge and trying to follow along :)

Comment: yeah what I am looking for is no commit if there are no changes, and a normal commit if there are changes...

Comment: That’s what `git merge --no-edit origin` is.

Comment: the problem, which is what the OP is talking about, is that in my testing `git merge --no-edit origin` produces new commits

Answer (score 1):

So as Ry- mentioned, if there were no changes in the remote branch, the output is `Already up to date.` and there is no commit.  Therefore, I'm not sure if this addresses the behavior you consider problematic, but I suspect it might:

So say you have a local change and a remote change, and you pull the remote with `git fetch` `git merge`
Your tree will look like this:

```
£ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
*   153b72e (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'b2'
|\
| * eb48067 (b2) b2 mod
* | 6397e45 master mod
|/
* 034e374 initial
```

We have the two actual commits, and now a merge commit.  A little messy for maybe a tiny config change checked in from a build machine or something.

So instead we can do it like this (instead of `git merge`):

```
£ git rebase b2
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: master mod
£ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
* 49de99c (HEAD -> master) master mod
* 5019681 (b2) b2 mod
* 1f8b73e initial
```

Aside from skipping the `merge commit`, this also skips `identical commits`.  In other words, it's kind of the thing to do if the remote branch isn't really something you consider a branch (even though it technically is).